# ConTeXt passing current counter value to lua

Tags: luatex, context, counters

I've been experimenting with ConTeXt and have been trying to create an exam using it.

I would like to have an array in lua that holds the weight of each question, and a custom enumeration called "question" that uses its own counter value to take the correct weighting from the array, and prints it next to the question number.

I haven't been able to get the counter value passed from tex to be properly interpreted in lua. It is correctly identified as a string, and lua prints out the string as the correct value, and I can even append more numbers to the string and it works correctly. But any attempt to convert the value to a number results in a nil value in Lua.

Does any one know what I'm doing wrong?

This is the basic code I've written, and when compiled under the current version of ConTeXt mkiv, it prints nil for both a and b. When compiling ConTeXt will pause and give me a "Please type a command or say `\end') prompt, and I think it may be somehow connected, but perhaps this is a separate issue.

```
\startluacode
    local lpeg = require"lpeg"
    userdata = userdata or {}
    qVals = {2, 3, 5, 10}
    function userdata.getQval(numb)
        local int = lpeg.S'+-'^-1 * lpeg.R'09'^1
        local a = lpeg.match(int,numb)
        local b = qVals[tonumber(numb)]
        context(type(numb) .. type(a) .. type(b) .. qVals[1])
    end
\stopluacode

\def\getQuestionVal#1{%
    \ctxlua{userdata.getQval([==[#1]==])}%
}

\defineenumeration[question]

\setupenumerations[question][
    text=\getQuestionVal{\getnumber[question]},
    headstyle=normal
]

\starttext
    \question This is the question
    \question Another
    \question and another
\stoptext
```

EDIT: After more hunting around I've concluded that `\getnumber[question]` is only expanded at the end, and so can't be used in indexing as-is. So now the question is how to force it to expand

Comment: The error may not be lua at all, but braces connected. What if you try with `text={\getQuestionVal{\getnumber[question]}}` ?

Comment: Just tried with the extra braces but unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: You need the `\rawcountervalue[<COUNTER>]` command to pass the value to Lua but you can also use the function `structures.counters.value(<COUNTER>)` to access the value from Lua itself.

Comment: Holy cow, that worked like a charm! thanks, I've been stuck on that issue for longer than I'd like to admit. is there a way for me to accept your comment as the correct answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Note

The names for advanced counter mechanism where changed a few years ago from `\definenumber` to `\definecounter` and the old names are just synonyms for the new command names.

## Example

The problem in your example is that you try to use the `\getnumber` command to pass the value to Lua but the `\getnumber` command itself is not expandable. To get value of the counter on the Lua side you have to use the expandable `\rawcountervalue` command, another method is to access the value from Lua with the `structures.counters.value` function.

```
\startluacode

function userdata.showcounter_value(value)
    context(tonumber(value))
end

function userdata.showcounter_name(name)
    context(structures.counters.value(name))
end

\stopluacode

\definecounter[testcounter]

\starttext

\incrementcounter[testcounter]

\ctxlua{userdata.showcounter_value(\rawcountervalue[testcounter])}

\incrementcounter[testcounter]

\ctxlua{userdata.showcounter_name("testcounter")}

\stoptext
```